# Initialize a struct with empty variables and make it globally available

Tags: swift, struct, global, init

What is the best solution for initializing a struct in swift with empty variables and make it accessible over more viewcontrollers? I know how to pass data between two viewcontrollers like:

```
let myVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondVC") as! SecondVC
myVC.stringPassed = myLabel.text!
```

But is there another elegant solution to make it accessible overall views.

Comment: Do you want to share data among different controllers?

Comment: Shared mutable state sounds like a bad idea. Parts of the code can mutate it without other parts knowing. Are you sure you want this? What is the data you want to share across all VCs?

Comment: yes, thats correct

Comment: @Sweeper, i also heared of it that it´s not a good design. I want to share a car structure with variables like brand, typ, engine and so on...

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a struct with a static variable.

```
struct CommonValues {
    static var text: String = ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create swift file and add following code

You should create `sharedInstance` so it won't initialise everytime

```
public class AppGlobalManager {

    // MARK: - Init 

    private init() {}

    // MARK: - Var

   static let sharedManager = AppGlobalManager()

   var name:String = ""
}
```

Now you can access it anywhere with just

```
AppGlobalManager.sharedManager.name
```

NOTE: It is not good practice to use this for passing data from viewcontroler  to view controller, You can use this for some global level objects like you can keep login user info here. and clear it when logout

Hope it is helpful

Comment: Singleton should have private init. Otherwise it is not really a singleton :)   because other classes will be able to create your singleton instance by themselves.

Comment: @Whirlwind will update soon thanks for suggesting I really appreciate it :)